# DynamoDB search object with queries filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

```
{
  "INFO": {
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "password": "123"
  },
  "PK": "3a95eab0-57de-4e15-90ea-004082e53384",
  "SK": "user"
}
```

Above is my dataset in dynamoDB. I am building login api with expressjs with dynamodb. I am able to scan and update data with PK & SK keys but i want to query inside my INFO set.

I am trying like this:

```
    var params = {
      TableName: "table",
      FilterExpression: "contains (INFO, :sendToVal)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":sendToVal": {
          email: "test@example.com",
          password: "123",
        },
      },
    };
```

But its returning:

```
{ error: 'Error retrieving Event' }
{ error: 'Event not found' }
```

Anyone help guide me, how can i retrive the set.

Answer (score 0):

The [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions) explains that the `contains()` function in an expression only works for strings or sets. This isn't completely accurate - it also works for lists. But in any case, it doesn't work for **maps**, which is what your `INFO` is, so the comparison doesn't match anything.

If you intended for `INFO` to be a list, not a map, please make it so. Otherwise, if you really intended for it to be a map, and you wanted to test whether `{ email: "test@example.com", password: "123" }` is in that map, then what you really need to check is whether the `email` and `password` entries in this map is equal to the desired value. So the filter condition can be something like `INFO.email = :email AND INFO.password = :password`. Or something like this (I'm not sure I understannd what your intention was here).

Comment: Can you help with current schema. I don't want to change this schema.

Comment: What about my second suggestion, the condition with the "AND"? I'm not sure I fully understood what your intention is, so if it's not exactly that, it's probably similar. But you can't use "contains()".

Comment: Can you elaborate by giving an example?

Comment: Elaborate on what? I suggested the FilterExpression `INFO.email = :email AND INFO.password = :password` (with ":email" and ":password" set in ExpressionAttributeValues, exactly like you did in your code).

Comment: Share it as Answer Please

Comment: Like this: FilterExpression: "contains (INFO.email = :email AND INFO.password = :password)" ?

Comment: No... No "contains".... Just "INFO.email = :email AND INFO.password = :password".

Comment: not following what you trying to say, can you elaborate your point with example?